# Update from SQL JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

Suppose I have a set of records with a `user_id` column on one table, and a `users` table, and both tables have an `email` column. How do I perform an `UPDATE` on the first table to set `mytable.user_id = users.id` where the email addresses match?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an `update` with a `join`.  The syntax varies between databases.  The MySQL syntax is:

```
update SetOfRecords sor join
       users u
       on sor.user_id = users.id
    set sor.email = u.email;
```

Postgres syntax is different, because it uses a `from` clause that comes after the `set`.  The ANSI standard syntax should work in both databases:

```
update SetOfRecords
    set email = (select max(email) from users u where SetOfRecords.user_id = u.id);
```

Comment: That makes sense, does it work if I want to set the `user_id` field instead of the email field, the value for which I already have in the record?

Comment: For Postgres, what worked for me was `UPDATE mytable SET user_id = users.id FROM users WHERE mytable.email = users.email`